# C Regular Expressions: Extracting the Actual Matches

Tags: c, regex, char

I am using regular expressions in C (using the "regex.h" library).  After setting up the standard calls (and checks) for regcomp(...) and regexec(...), I can only manage to print the actual substrings that match my compiled regular expression.
Using regexec, according to the manual pages, means you store the substring matches in a structure known as "regmatch_t".  The struct only contains rm_so and rm_eo to reference what I understand to be the addresses of the characters of the matched substring in memory, but my question is how can I just use these to offsets and two pointers to extract the actual substring and store it into an array (ideally a 2D array of strings)?

It works when you just print to standard out, but whenever you try to use the same setup but store it in a string/character array, it stores the entire string that was originally used to match against the expression.
Further, what is the "%.*s" inside the print statement?  I imagine it's a regular expression in of itself to read in the pointers to a character array correctly.  I just want to store the matched substrings inside a collection so I can work with them elsewhere in my software.

Background:  p and p2 are both pointers set to point to the start of string to match before entering the while loop in the code below:
[EDIT:  "matches" is a 2D array meant to ultimately store the substring matches and was preallocated/initalized before the main loop you see below]

```
int ind = 0;
while(1){
    regExErr1 = regexec(&r, p, 10, m, 0);
    //printf("Did match regular expr, value %i\n", regExErr1);
    if( regExErr1 != 0 ){ 
        fprintf(stderr, "No more matches with the inherent regular expression!\n"); 
        break; 
    }   
    printf("What was found was: ");
    int i = 0;
    while(1){
        if(m[i].rm_so == -1){
            break;
        }
        int start = m[i].rm_so + (p - p2);
        int finish = m[i].rm_eo + (p - p2);
        strcpy(matches[ind], ("%.*s\n", (finish - start), p2 + start));
        printf("Storing:  %.*s", matches[ind]);
        ind++;
        printf("%.*s\n", (finish - start), p2 + start);
        i++;
    }
    p += m[0].rm_eo; // this will move the pointer p to the end of last matched pattern and on to the start of a new one
}
printf("We have in [0]:  %s\n", temp);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are quite a lot of regular expression packages, but yours seems to match the one in POSIX: [`regcomp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html) etc.

The two structures it defines in `<regex.h>` are:

- `regex_t` containing at least `size_t re_nsub`, the number of parenthesized subexpressions.
- `regmatch_t` containing at least `regoff_t rm_so`, the byte offset from start of string to start of substring, and `regoff_t rm_eo`, the byte offset from start of string of the first character after the end of substring.

Note that 'offsets' are not pointers but indexes into the character array.

The execution function is:

- `int regexec(const regex_t *restrict preg, const char *restrict string,
     size_t nmatch, regmatch_t pmatch[restrict], int eflags);`

Your printing code should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= r.re_nsub; i++)
{
    int start = m[i].rm_so;
    int finish = m[i].rm_eo;
//  strcpy(matches[ind], ("%.*s\n", (finish - start), p + start));  // Based on question
    sprintf(matches[ind], "%.*s\n", (finish - start), p + start);   // More plausible code
    printf("Storing:  %.*s\n", (finish - start), matches[ind]);     // Print once
    ind++;
    printf("%.*s\n", (finish - start), p + start);                  // Why print twice?
}
```

Note that the code should be upgraded to ensure that the string copy (via `sprintf()`) does not overflow the target string — maybe by using `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`.  It is also a good idea to mark the start and end of a string in the printing. For example:

```
    printf("<<%.*s>>\n", (finish - start), p + start);
```

This makes it a whole heap easier to see spaces etc.

*[In future, please attempt to provide an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or  SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that people can help more easily.]*

This is an SSCCE that I created, probably in response to another SO question in 2010.  It is one of a number of programs I keep that I call 'vignettes'; little programs that show the essence of some feature (such as POSIX regexes, in this case).  I find them useful as memory joggers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <regex.h>

#define tofind    "^DAEMONS=\\(([^)]*)\\)[ \t]*$"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[1024];
    int retval = 0;
    regex_t re;
    regmatch_t rm[2];
    //this file has this line "DAEMONS=(sysklogd network sshd !netfs !crond)"
    const char *filename = "/etc/rc.conf";

    if (argc > 1)
        filename = argv[1];

    if (regcomp(&re, tofind, REG_EXTENDED) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to compile regex '%s'\n", tofind);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Regex: %s\n", tofind);
    printf("Number of captured expressions: %zu\n", re.re_nsub);

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s (%d: %s)\n", filename, errno, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((fgets(line, 1024, fp)) != NULL)
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        if ((retval = regexec(&re, line, 2, rm, 0)) == 0)
        {
            printf("<<%s>>\n", line);
            // Complete match
            printf("Line: <<%.*s>>\n", (int)(rm[0].rm_eo - rm[0].rm_so), line + rm[0].rm_so);
            // Match captured in (...) - the \( and \) match literal parenthesis
            printf("Text: <<%.*s>>\n", (int)(rm[1].rm_eo - rm[1].rm_so), line + rm[1].rm_so);
            char *src = line + rm[1].rm_so;
            char *end = line + rm[1].rm_eo;
            while (src < end)
            {
                size_t len = strcspn(src, " ");
                if (src + len > end)
                    len = end - src;
                printf("Name: <<%.*s>>\n", (int)len, src);
                src += len;
                src += strspn(src, " ");
            }
        }
    } 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This was designed to find a particular line starting `DAEMONS=` in a file `/etc/rc.conf` (but you can specify an alternative file name on the command line).  You can adapt it to your purposes easily enough.

Comment: Yes, you are right Jonathan, I neglected to mention that I was using POSIX for regular expressions.  Your code recommendation did the trick (for printing that is), however, I had to convert it to a while-loop due to a compiler complaint I was not allowed to use a for-loop since apparently I wasn't using C99.
I have one other question:  what does the expression "<<%.*s>>" mean?  (within the <<>>) and why does it require two arguments (the offset subtraction calculation and the actual string)?

Comment: The `<<` and `>>` are simply a pair of 'bracketing' characters that seldom show up in my work (but I don't play with XML or HTML all day).  You can use `"[[%.*s]]"` or `"XX%.*sXX"` or any other character or characters you choose; they're there to mark the start and end of the string, that's all.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't clear.  I mean, what does `%.*s` mean?  and why does it use the two arguments you provide it?

Comment: Ah; you need to read the manual ([`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), but be cautious about the POSIX extensions; they're clearly marked, though).  However, the `*` means that there's an `int` argument (and I should probably have added casts to ensure that an `int` is passed) that specifies the maximum length of the string.  If there's a NUL `'\0'` before that, it will stop there, but when the string is longer, the length specified by the `*` parameter is the maximum length printed.

Comment: Incidentally, if you're not using C99, you can declare the loop index outside the loop, and then just write `for (i = 0; i < r.re_nsub; i++) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank for all of your help Jonathan.  I got it to work using your suggestion, but interestingly enough, I had to use the original while-loop construct you see in my code sample above.  For some reason re_nsub is coming up as 0 [I must have forgotten a parameter somewhere along the line], even though I get no errors from the regular expression compiling (using regcomp(...)).
My construct had to be (which works):
`while(1){
      if(m[i].rm_so == -1){
           break;
      }
...
}`
[Alternatively the halting condition could be written within the loop conditional.]

Comment: I found that the first match result, e.g. `m[0]`, will be the full matched text. So the loop should be `i <= r.re_nsub` to get all of your matches.

Answer (score 0):

Since g++ regex is bugged until who knows when, you can use my code instead (License: AGPL, no warranty, your own risk, ...)

```
/**
 * regexp (License: AGPL3 or higher)
 * @param re extended POSIX regular expression
 * @param nmatch maximum number of matches
 * @param str string to match
 * @return An array of char pointers. You have to free() the first element (string storage). the second element is the string matching the full regex, then come the submatches.
*/
char **regexp(char *re, int nmatch, char *str) {
  char **result;
  char *string;
  regex_t regex;
  regmatch_t *match;
  int i;

  match=malloc(nmatch*sizeof(*match));
  if (!result) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory !");
    return NULL;
  }

  if (regcomp(&regex, re, REG_EXTENDED)!=0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to compile regex '%s'\n", re);
    return NULL;
  }

  string=strdup(str);
  if (regexec(&regex,string,nmatch,match,0)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "String '%s' does not match regex '%s'\n",str,re);
#endif
    free(string);
    return NULL;
  }

  result=malloc(sizeof(*result));
  if (!result) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory !");
    free(string);
    return NULL;
  }

  for (i=0; i<nmatch; ++i) {
    if (match[i].rm_so>=0) {
      string[match[i].rm_eo]=0;
      ((char**)result)[i]=string+match[i].rm_so;
#ifdef DEBUG
      printf("%s\n",string+match[i].rm_so);
#endif                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    } else {                             
      ((char**)result)[i]="";            
    }
  }

  result[0]=string;                      

  return result;                         

}
```