# regexec does not return multiple matches

Tags: regex, posix

Tried to learn posix regex with this example [enter link description here](http://www.lemoda.net/c/unix-regex/) and my own regex and text.

```
    const char * regex_text = "[[:digit:]]{2}\\:[[:digit:]]{2}\\:[[:digit:]]{2},[[:digit:]]{3}";
    const char * find_text = "00:01:54,644 --> 00:01:56,714 --> 00:02:58,589";
```

The output:

```
Trying to find '[[:digit:]]{2}\:[[:digit:]]{2}\:[[:digit:]]{2},[[:digit:]]{3}' in '00:01:54,644 --> 00:01:56,714 --> 00:02:58,589'
$& is '00:01:54,644' (bytes 0:12)
$& is '00:01:56,714' (bytes 17:29)
$& is '00:02:58,589' (bytes 34:46)
No more matches.
```

My question is why only one match was found in each of the `for` loops? And instead, the `while` loop did the job. Shouldn't one `regexec` return all matches to `m`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide the full relevant code, state the language/library. Read the docs first. Logically, `while` loops through the whole string, and `if` only checks for one match, isn't that normal?

Comment: @Wiktor, please read the link I refer to in my post. Answers to the questions you asked are all there. I've also mentioned I am learning posix regex. I tried to include all coding here, but the site rejected it because too many codes. That's why I use the link. In fact most of my code is copied from the link except those I include in my post. I don't think down voting me is appropriate.

Comment: You might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238468/c-regular-expressions-extracting-the-actual-matches). Actually, all code should be included into the question body. You did not post what you actually used and where.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop would catch all the capture groups within a match (groups enclosed in parentheses). So if you had written

```
([[:digit:]]{2}\\:[[:digit:]]{2}\\:[[:digit:]]{2},[[:digit:]]{3}) --> ([[:digit:]]{2}\\:[[:digit:]]{2}\\:[[:digit:]]{2},[[:digit:]]{3}) --> ([[:digit:]]{2}\\:[[:digit:]]{2}\\:[[:digit:]]{2},[[:digit:]]{3})
```

as your regex, your three timestamps would show up in $1, $2, and $3.

In your code, however, the regex matches only one timestamp. If you want to catch the next one, you need to execute a new match, which is what the `while` loop does.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Your regex works but it is specific to the string I use. Could it be modified so that it will work if the no. of timpstamp is unknown?

Comment: `regexec()` should return all matches. That's why `m` is an array of `regmatch_t`. Obviously my regex is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer the question, it is normal that a single call to `regexec()` only returns the first match of the regex, hence the need for an outer loop to iterate through all matches.

The confusion comes from the fact that the `regmatch_t` array only describes *one* match of the regex (is is an array because it has to contain the offsets of the match itself, and the offsets of each sub-expression within that match).