# Regular expression matching using regcomp() and regexec() functions in C

Tags: c, regex, linux

Am not familiar to use the [regex library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) on C language. Currently am trying to use [Regexec() and Regcomp()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html) functions to search for a string that matches my pattern or regular expression. but i can*t generate my matched string. do i miss something on my code, or any fault usage with the functions?

my sample code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    regex_t r;
    const char * my_regex = "(\\d+.\\d+.\\d+.\\d+)";
    const char * my_string = "Am trying to match any ip like, 23.54.67.89 , in this string and 123.232.123.33 is possible";
    const int no_of_matches = 10;
    regmatch_t m[no_of_matches];

    printf ("Trying to match '%s' in '%s'\n", my_regex, my_string);
    int status = regcomp (&r, my_regex, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE);
    printf("status: %d\n",status);
    if(status!=0)
    {
        printf ("Regex error compiling \n");
    }
    int match_size = regexec (&r, my_string, no_of_matches, m, 0);
    printf("Number of Matches : %d\n",match_size);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < match_size; i++) 
    {
        //Now i wana print all matches here,
        int start = m[i].rm_so;
        int finish = m[i].rm_eo;
        printf("%.*s\n", (finish - start), my_string + start);
    }
    regfree (& r);
    return 0;
}
```

Here,to the problem: i can*t print my matches. any suggestion? am on linux.
I have edited my for loop, now it prints:

```
Trying to match '(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)' in 'Am trying to match any ip like, 23.54.67.89 , in this string and 123.232.123.33 is possible'
status: 0
Number of Matches : 1
m trying to match any ip like, 23.54.67.89 , in this string and 123.232.123.33 is possible
```

But am expecting my out put as:

```
Trying to match '(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)' in 'Am trying to match any ip like, 23.54.67.89 , in this string and 123.232.123.33 is possible'
status: 0
Number of Matches : 2
23.54.67.89
123.232.123.33
```

Comment: Check [C Regular Expressions: Extracting the Actual Matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238468/c-regular-expressions-extracting-the-actual-matches)

Answer (score 5):

Your regular expression is not a POSIX regular expression. You're using Perl/Tcl/Vim flavour, which won't work like you hope it would.

[`regcomp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html) and [`regexec()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regexec.3.html) are [POSIX regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), and as such, are part of POSIX-compliant (or just POSIX-y) C libraries. They are not just part of some regex library; these are the POSIX standard stuff.

In particular, POSIX regular expressions do not recognize `\d`, or any other backslash-character classes. You should use `[[:digit:]]` instead. (The character classes are enclosed in brackets, so to match any digit or lowercase letter you could use `[[:digit:][:lower:]]`. For anything except a control character, you could use `[^[:cntrl:]]`.)

In general, you can check out the [Character classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions#Character_classes) table in the [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions) Wikipedia article, which contains a concise summary of the equivalent classes with descriptions.

Do you need a locale-aware example to demonstrate this?