# Iterating through lines of file and exporting variables to env

Tags: c

I'm actually trying to iterate through a file and exporting all variables from it for current child process that's for current c program so I think a export can do what I want but problem is that I'm lacking a proper approach.
Can you help please?

https://del.dog/adoduyegig.cc :

```
void parse_file(char* filename) {
    regex_t reg;
    FILE* file;
    char line[20];
    char buf[250];
    int regs=regcomp(&reg,"([^#]+)(\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).*", REG_EXTENDED);

    if(!filename)
        filename="a.sh";

    if(!(file=fopen(filename,"r")))
        printf("Can't locate %s",filename);

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        if(!(regs=regexec(&reg, line, 0, NULL, 0))) {
            sprintf(buf, "export %s",line);
            system(buf);
        }
    }
    regfree(&reg);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: You export is done in a temporary shell stopping its execution just after execution the export, that does nothing finally

Comment: export a=b, isn't this will export variable a to environment and than I can access it's value through getenv anywhere in my program?

Comment: @Rohit you need to memorize all the strings like "a=b" in an array of char* to be able to give it to execle or equivalent

Comment: I have that code also, I want to go through each line and I don't actually know the size of the file can this assumption be removed?

Comment: @Rohit other way : you use the function `int setenv(const char *name, const char *value, int overwrite);` if it is not a problem then you will call the child

Comment: @Rohit the size is not a problem the function _realloc_ is made for that

Comment: Than there'll be a problem in this approach. for setenv I need to get value after = and also need to separate varname before = . Than it'll consume more time

Comment: @Rohit more time to write the program ? ;-) If _regexec_ is able to extract the settings I don't think it is really more complicated

Comment: It'll take more time in executing as I have to take two regex in this case and that'll take memory as well as time

Comment: Note that each time you run `system()`, the shell that it invokes sets the shell variable (it doesn't seem to export it, so it doesn't become an environment variable), but the shell terminates, losing the assignment.  Under normal circumstances, the child process cannot affect the environment of the parent process.  (Abnormal circumstances include if the child process attaches a debugger to the parent and then tinkers with the parent's environment — not child's play, even if it is the child process that does it.)  So, this process is going to have to rethink the whole approach.

Comment: I just want to export all the variables so that they can be accessed anywhere in the whole c program with getenv

Comment: Are you on a POSIX-compliant machine?  If so, you need to use [`setenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html).  If not, you need to look at alternatives.  The `putenv()` function exists sometimes (or maybe `_putenv()`), but you have to use caution when you use it; read the man page carefully.  Otherwise, it depends on the local facilities.  You might be able to get away with manufacturing an environment and setting the global variable `environ` to point to the revised environment, but it is _not_ (repeat **not**) recommended.

Answer (score 0):

To give environment variables to a child process you can

- create the *envp* vector of char * to give it to `int execvpe(const char *file, char *const argv[],char *const envp[]);` or equivalent function, each entry in the vector having the form "a=b"
- or if it is not a problem for the current program to set the environment using `int setenv(const char *name, const char *value, int overwrite);` for all the required variables then create your child process

Comment: @Rohit I have absolutely no idea about what regexec returns, I can just give you a general example

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions

Comment: @Rohit  imagined you defined it

Comment: Oh. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238468/c-regular-expressions-extracting-the-actual-matches I hope I can get matched string with this